# creating asn1parse , crl and getting pem using pyOpenSSL

Tags: openssl, cryptography, x509, pem, pyopenssl

I am currently using `openSSL` commands to parse a signed file, extract `.clrs` and convert to `.pem` at last.

to parse the signed file into asn1parse_content.txt
`openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in signed.p7s >> asn1parse_content.txt`

to extract crl content from signed.p7s using offsets and lengths got from asn1parse_content.txt
`dd if=signed.p7s of=crl1.crl bs=1 count=5000 skip=4000`

convert to pem from crl
`openssl crl -inform DER -in crl1.crl -outform PEM -out crl1_pem.pem`

I need to do the same things using python `pyOpenSSL` module in **windows**, have checked SO for related posts, but none matches my requirement, most of the posts are related to RSA keys, private/public keys, and direct extraction of `.pem` from `.p7s` etc.

I am very much new to `python` and `OpenSSL` and have come up with a small program going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344287/extract-signed-data-from-pkcs7-in-python)

Below is the program to get asn1parse data from the p7s file.

```
import sys
from OpenSSL import crypto
from OpenSSL._util import (
    ffi as _ffi,
    lib as _lib,
)
p7s_file = sys.argv[1]
with open(p7s_file, 'rb') as f:
    p7data = f.read()
p7 = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, p7data)
print p7
```

Actual Output

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py:14: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
> from cryptography import utils, x509
> <OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS7 object at 0x000000000359DE48>

But was expecting a series of lines like below

> 0:d=0  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE
> 2:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-signedData
> 13:d=1  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]
> 15:d=2  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE
> 17:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
> 20:d=3  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SET
> 22:d=4  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
> 24:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256
> 35:d=5  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
> 37:d=3  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE
> 39:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
> 50:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC
> and many other lines

I am extracting the `crl` content using `dd` command by using the *offset* i.e the first value, *hl* and *l*

I would appreciate any help with references and examples in this regard.

following are the post i have checked already
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673910/windows-crl-to-pem-for-nginx)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681409/converting-a-certificate-revocation-list-crl-file-from-crl-to-pem-extension)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64393432/openssl-asn1parse-does-not-extract-data-correctly)

and many others

**Update 1:**

to the above code, I have added the below lines

```
pkcs7_PEM = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p7data)
pkcs7_crl = pkcs7_PEM.get_crls()
print pkcs7_crl
```

then I got this error

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py:14: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
> from cryptography import utils, x509
> <OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS7 object at 0x000000000360EE80>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "asn1_check.py", line 51, in 
> pkcs7_PEM = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p7data)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 3131, in load_pkcs7_data
> _raise_current_error()
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL_util.py", line 57, in exception_from_error_queue
> raise exception_type(errors)
> OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', 'get_name', 'no start line')]

Comment: Although [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104923/pyopenssls-pkcs7-object-provide-very-little-information-how-can-i-get-the-sha1) asks about something rather different, the A links to [a pull request](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/pull/367) that (in the Files changed tab) includes code for `get_crls`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, i think i have alreay used the right function `load_pkcs7_data`, but output it produces it not what i am expecting, i have updated my question with more details, can you please check once. and when i added code for `get_crls()`, then i got different set of errors.

Comment: Your file is apparently 'ASN1' format (what OpenSSL usually calls DER) and not PEM. You previously loaded it successfully as ASN1; continue to do that.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks ,after `p7 = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, p7data)` , now p7 is an object of `OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS7`, how will we get the `crl` data out of that, which functions to use?

Comment: I tried using `pkcs7_crl = p7.get_crls() print pkcs7_crl`, but getting error `AttributeError: 'PKCS7' object has no attribute 'get_crls'`

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `<(type) object at (address)>` AND the traceback with `no start line`? That's inconsistent and illogical. If you're getting _only_ the traceback, check your file; it has apparently been damaged (perhaps truncated).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, that _<(type) object at (address)>_ is coming from  `p7 = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, p7data)` `print p7`, after that i used `get_crl()` on `pkcs7_PEM` as mentioned in the **Update1**, that is causing the traceback and which seems its not correct way of using

Comment: And why am i not getting replies, not sure i am asking it correctly or there is very less crowd out there about the subject(i doubt the second), but still i would like to receive inputs even if it is -ve, so that i can improve myself.

Comment: Your file is apparently DER not PEM, so `load_pkcs7_data` with `FILETYPE_ASN1` does work and doing it with `FILETYPE_PEM` does NOT work. Don't do the approach which does not work. Do the approach which does work. Once you have the `pkcs7` object how you process it does not depend on how it was read. The pull request I linked to was apparently not accepted into the project, so you can't just use `p7.get_crls`, you need to either 'monkeypatch' your object to add it, or write it as separate code (what C++ would call a 'friend' routine, but python doesn't have a term for this that I know of).

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085, but  I feet really strange that we have no way to read p7s file using pyopenssl

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, can you please help in migrating this post to _crypto.stackexchange.com_, hope  i may get some more responses there. I couldn't find a way to migrate this by self.

Comment: I am voting to close this question here and request to migrate this to other site such as serverfault, crypto, security or other sites where more **active OpenSSL** discussions happen.